# Image blurring with css animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I really don't see any solutions for this one so I try here aswell.

Here's the situation I have : I have this 2 images here that are blurring when other images (the tools floating) are being animated by a transform proporty (translateY).

Here's a image comparison : [image: Image without animations]

This one is without the animations. And now, the second one with them : [image: Image with animation]

I don't see where's my problem. I tried applying backface-visibility or translate (0,0,0) but it does work only on chrome. This problem is also applied to the text on the same div however it's not as noticeable as the images.

Do you guys have faced this problem before ? If yes, what is the solution ?

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: Can you share your css code?

Comment: Tried to replicate it as much as possible : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOdJWo

@fcalderan

Comment: why don't you use a 90x75 image?

Comment: fixed @fcalderan